# Combine two MYSQL table with same column Name

Tags: mysql

I have two table

table one  is scheduletime

```
id    |   edition    | time   | 
1     |       1      | 9:23am |
2     |       2      | 10:23am|
```

table two is actualtime

```
id    | edition  | time    |
1     |    1     | 10:23am |
2     |    2     | 11:23am |
```

I want to result as

```
Caption    | Edition    | Time    |
Scheduleed |    1       |  9:23am |
actual     |    1       |  10:23am |
Scheduleed |    2       |  10:23am |
actual     |    2       |  11:23am |
```

How can do this in MySQL ?

Comment: I did not even know where to start with a query like this and needed the same thing.  I'm really glad you asked this question as it helped me TREMENDOUSLY with both the answer and the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT  Caption, Edition, Time
FROM
        (
            SELECT  'Scheduled' Caption, Edition, time
            FROM    scheduleTime
            UNION   ALL
            SELECT  'Actual' Caption, Edition, time
            FROM    scheduleTime
        ) subquery
ORDER   BY Edition, FIELD(Caption, 'Scheduled', 'Actual')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2c0d/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*without using `FIELD()`, just plain `ORDER BY...DESC`*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2c0d/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║  CAPTION  ║ EDITION ║  TIME   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ Scheduled ║       1 ║ 9:23am  ║
║ Actual    ║       1 ║ 9:23am  ║
║ Scheduled ║       2 ║ 10:23am ║
║ Actual    ║       2 ║ 10:23am ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: both FROM    scheduleTime? 
Or from the two different tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(select 'Scheduleed' as Caption, Edition as Edition, Time as Time from scheduletime

union all

select 'actual' as Caption, Edition as Edition, Time as Time from actualtime) as a

order by Edition
```

Maybe this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    'Scheduleed' AS Caption, 
    Edition, 
    time 
FROM scheduletime
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'actual' AS Caption, 
    Edition, 
    time 
FROM actualtime
ORDER BY Edition, Caption DESC
```

OUTPUT:

```
|    CAPTION | EDITION |    TIME |
----------------------------------
| Scheduleed |       1 |  9:23am |
|     actual |       1 | 10:23am |
| Scheduleed |       2 | 10:23am |
|     actual |       2 | 11:23am |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/086157/8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :-

```
select * from(
select 'Scheduleed' as Caption ,edition,time from scheduletime

union all

select 'actual' as Caption,edition,time from actualtime
)x
```