# php/mysql Merge 2 tables with same Columns correctly

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT: Thanks For JoseCarlosPB here is the solution:

```
SELECT
  (select count(DISTINCT userscount) AS duplicates from users1)
  +
  (select count(DISTINCT userscount) AS duplicates from users2) AS duplicates
FROM dual;
```

So i have 2 tables and a mysql statement i want to merge 2 tables but there is same column in both.I think There is nothing to do in PHP code i think the problem is in the mysql statement.

my code works(no errors) but it gives unexpected output.i simply want to correctly count userscount here is what i mean:
table1 has 32 users and table2 has 44 users
i thought the output will be 76 users but it is 3244

PHP:

```
include 'conn00.php';
    $sql = "select DISTINCT userscount, count(DISTINCT userscount) AS duplicates from users1 UNION ALL
     select DISTINCT userscount, count(DISTINCT userscount) AS duplicates from users2";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["duplicates"];
        }
    } else {

    }
```

table1:

```
users1 

32
```

table2:

```
users2 

44
```

output: 3244 i want the output to be 76

If the solution is in mysql will be better bcz i have more similar sql statements and i want apply the solution for all of it.
thanks for answering

Comment: Use two different aliases and add those 2 up.

Comment: instead of `echo $row["duplicates"]` use `$count[] = $row["duplicates"];` then after while loop you can get sum using `echo array_sum($count)`;

Comment: You're using `AS duplicates` for both. Try doing `AS duplicates1` and `AS duplicates2` then add both of them; that should work.

Comment: @Akam i get http error

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner `echo $row["duplicates"]+["duplicates1"];` i get error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner http error

Comment: That's it? That's the error you get back? Did you check your logs? There stands to have more info in there. Place the following after your opening php tag `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. If this is a mysql error, then use  `mysqli_error($conn)` for the query and see what that produces. Are the values' column type text or integer? Did you also modify your query per what I suggested you try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can do it this way, almost like [alistaircol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59285483/5873008) said

```
SELECT
  (select count(DISTINCT userscount) AS duplicates from users1)
  +
  (select count(DISTINCT userscount) AS duplicates from users2) AS duplicates
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check article you need [Combine two MYSQL table with same column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117306/combine-two-mysql-table-with-same-column-name)

Just comparing to this you need to move count outside of UNION in order to work as you expected

Comment: not sure how to do it his code is different than mine

Comment: please give sql export (you can do some fake data) so i can do the real code for you

Comment: That's exactly the full code i use to output the sql using PHP...as i said it works fine i just want to add them together 32+44... using sql ofc.

Comment: give me just structure of table users1

Comment: sir, export so i can import it in sql and try it, there is no all fields from query so i cannot test it and give you working query... please

Comment: thank you so much for your time but i already found the answer

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try something like this for your query:

```
SELECT
  (select count(DISTINCT userscount) AS duplicates from users1 group by usercount)
  +
  (select count(DISTINCT userscount) AS duplicates from users2 group by usercount)
FROM dual;
```

> DUAL is purely for the convenience of people who require that all SELECT statements should have FROM and possibly other clauses. MySQL may ignore the clauses. MySQL does not require FROM DUAL if no tables are referenced.

More info about `DUAL`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change your code query into this to sum the entire counting value

```
      include 'conn00.php';
    $sql = "select  sum(i) as duplicates from (
    select count(DISTINCT  userscount) as i from users1 union all
    select count(DISTINCT  userscount) as i from users2 
    ) x";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["duplicates"];
        }
    } else {

    }
```

Comment: sorry i miss some code maybe you can use this if you have more than 2 users table

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if the semantics of the query was correct, but the syntax must be like this (WHERE clause goes after JOIN and ON):

```
 SELECT users1.text1, users2.name,users2.email, 
 users1.username
 FROM users1 
 INNER JOIN users2 
 ON users1.text1=users2.text1
 WHERE users1.username = $_SESSION[username]
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * from 
 ( (select count(DISTINCT userscount) AS duplicates from users1)
     union all 
   (select count(DISTINCT userscount) AS duplicates from users2) 
 )  as duplicates`

You can also merge in this way.hope it was helpful